# Replace rbind in for-loop with lapply? (2nd circle of hell)

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, lapply, rbind

I am having trouble optimising a piece of R code. The following example code should illustrate my optimisation problem:

Some initialisations and a function definition:

```
a <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80)
b <- c(“a”,”b”,”c”,”d”,”z”,”g”,”h”,”r”)
c <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
myframe <- data.frame(a,b,c)
values <- vector(length=columns)
solution <- matrix(nrow=nrow(myframe),ncol=columns+3)

myfunction <- function(frame,columns){
athing = 0
   if(columns == 5){
   athing = 100
   }
   else{
   athing = 1000
   }
value[colums+1] = athing
return(value)}
```

**The problematic for-loop looks like this:**

```
columns = 6
for(i in 1:nrow(myframe){
   values <- myfunction(as.matrix(myframe[i,]), columns)
   values[columns+2] = i
   values[columns+3] = myframe[i,3]
   #more columns added with simple operations (i.e. sum)

   solution <- rbind(solution,values)
   #solution is a large matrix from outside the for-loop
}
```

**The problem seems to be the `rbind` function.** I frequently get error messages regarding the size of `solution` which seems to be to large after a while (more than 50 MB).
I want to replace this loop and the `rbind` with a list and `lapply` and/or foreach. I have started with converting `myframe`to a list.

```
myframe_list <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(myframe)), function(i) myframe[i,])
```

I have not really come further than this, although I tried applying this [very good introduction to parallel processing](http://beckmw.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/a-brief-foray-into-parallel-processing-with-r/).

How do I have to reconstruct the for-loop without having to change `myfunction`? Obviously I am open to different solutions...

Edit: This problem seems to be straight from the [2nd circle of hell from the R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `columns`? Do I understand well, the `value` is vector with 2 possible values: 100 and 1000?

Comment: Before the for-loop it is...
`columns` is a is a changing number of columns of the `values-frame` and `solutions-martrix`. Depending on a specific input (in the actual script 10000+ columns are possible).
`myfunction`is far more complex in the actual script. Still it is just a series of if-branches. Each `values-frame` is built by the for-loop and `myfunction` and rbinded to the `solutions` matrix.

Comment: Dyd you try instead `solution <- rbind(solution,values)` try `solution[i,] = values`? As I understand, you got already created `solution` matric, so there is no need to bind next rows. Changing existing row od NA's to `value` is more efficient. Perhaps that will do the job?

Comment: `solution`is already created but "not complete" as the for-loop on display here is inside another for-loop that relies on `solution`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason that using `rbind` in a loop like this is bad practice, is that in each iteration you enlarge your `solution` data frame and then copy it to a new object, which is a very slow process and can also lead to memory problems. One way around this is to create a list, whose ith component will store the output of the ith loop iteration. The final step is to call rbind on that list (just once at the end). This will look something like

```
my.list <- vector("list", nrow(myframe))
for(i in 1:nrow(myframe)){
    # Call all necessary commands to create values
    my.list[[i]] <- values
}
solution <- rbind(solution, do.call(rbind, my.list))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much. It reduces the execution time on my machine from 40 mins to 2 mins with the lowest possible `columns`.
BTW: Last thing I tried was `solution <- do.call('rbind',my.list)`. This obviously did not work.
Thanks again!

Comment: For solution part , you may just use this. `do.call(Map, c(rbind, my.list))`

Comment: This is how to do it, but keep in mind base::rbind requires "fifty times more RAM and is more than 15 times slower than dplyr::bind_rows" [1]  

[1] [Difference between rbind() and bind_rows() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887217/difference-between-rbind-and-bind-rows-in-r)

Answer (score -1):

A bit to long for comment, so I put it here:
If `columns` is known in advance:

```
    myfunction <- function(frame){
    athing = 0
       if(columns == 5){
       athing = 100
       }
       else{
       athing = 1000
       }
    value[colums+1] = athing
    return(value)}

    apply(myframe, 2, myfunction)
```

If `columns` is not given via environment, you can use:

`apply(myframe, 2, myfunction, columns)` with your original `myfunction` definition.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how this would lead to the same result. ;)
Where would my `solution-matrix`be in this case? Where are the columns added from the original for-loop?