# Difference between rbind() and bind_rows() in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rbind

On the web, I found that **`rbind()`** is used to combine two data frames by rows, and the same task is performed by **`bind_rows()`** function from `dplyr`.

What's the difference between these two functions, and which one is more efficient?

Comment: It has additional arguments like `.id` etc in `bind_rows`.   `bind_rows` can bind multiple datasets in a `list` whereas `rbind` does only 2 datasets unless you do `do.call`.  Regarding the efficiency, it is easier to check with `system.time` or `microbenchmark` on a large dataset when you get some time

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Apart from few more differences, one of the main reasons for using `bind_rows` over `rbind` is to combine two data frames having different number of columns. `rbind` throws an error in such a case whereas `bind_rows` assigns "`NA`" to those rows of columns missing in one of the data frames where the value is not provided by the data frames.

Try out the following code to see the difference:

```
a <- data.frame(a = 1:2, b = 3:4, c = 5:6)
b <- data.frame(a = 7:8, b = 2:3, c = 3:4, d = 8:9)
```

Results for the two calls are as follows:

```
rbind(a, b)
> rbind(a, b)
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(a, b)
> bind_rows(a, b)
  a b c  d
1 1 3 5 NA
2 2 4 6 NA
3 7 2 3  8
4 8 3 4  9
```

Answer (score 56):

Since none of the answers here offers a systematic review of the differences between `base::rbind` and `dplyr::bind_rows`, and the answer from @bob regarding performance is incorrect, I decided to add the following.

Let's have some testing data frame:

```
df_1 = data.frame(
  v1_dbl = 1:1000,
  v2_lst = I(as.list(1:1000)),
  v3_fct = factor(sample(letters[1:10], 1000, replace = TRUE)),
  v4_raw = raw(1000),
  v5_dtm = as.POSIXct(paste0("2019-12-0", sample(1:9, 1000, replace = TRUE)))
)

df_1$v2_lst = unclass(df_1$v2_lst) #remove the AsIs class introduced by `I()`
```

#### 1. `base::rbind` handles list inputs differently

```
rbind(list(df_1, df_1))
     [,1]   [,2]  
[1,] List,5 List,5

# You have to combine it with `do.call()` to achieve the same result:
head(do.call(rbind, list(df_1, df_1)), 3)
  v1_dbl v2_lst v3_fct v4_raw     v5_dtm
1      1      1      b     00 2019-12-02
2      2      2      h     00 2019-12-08
3      3      3      c     00 2019-12-09

head(dplyr::bind_rows(list(df_1, df_1)), 3)
  v1_dbl v2_lst v3_fct v4_raw     v5_dtm
1      1      1      b     00 2019-12-02
2      2      2      h     00 2019-12-08
3      3      3      c     00 2019-12-09
```

#### 2. `base::rbind` can cope with (some) mixed types

While both `base::rbind` and `dplyr::bind_rows` fail when trying to bind eg. raw or datetime column to a column of some other type, `base::rbind` can cope with some degree of discrepancy.

Combining a list and a non-list column produces a list column. Combining a factor and something else produces a warning but not an error:

```
df_2 = data.frame(
  v1_dbl = 1,
  v2_lst = 1,
  v3_fct = 1,
  v4_raw = raw(1),
  v5_dtm = as.POSIXct("2019-12-01")
)

head(rbind(df_1, df_2), 3)
  v1_dbl v2_lst v3_fct v4_raw     v5_dtm
1      1      1      b     00 2019-12-02
2      2      2      h     00 2019-12-08
3      3      3      c     00 2019-12-09
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = 1) : invalid factor level, NA generated

# Fails on the lst, num combination:
head(dplyr::bind_rows(df_1, df_2), 3)
Error: Column `v2_lst` can't be converted from list to numeric

# Fails on the fct, num combination:
head(dplyr::bind_rows(df_1[-2], df_2), 3)
Error: Column `v3_fct` can't be converted from factor to numeric
```

#### 3. `base::rbind` keeps rownames

Tidyverse advocates making rownames into a dedicated column, so its functions drop them.

```
rbind(mtcars[1:2, 1:4], mtcars[3:4, 1:4])
                mpg cyl disp  hp
Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110
Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110
Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110

dplyr::bind_rows(mtcars[1:2, 1:4], mtcars[3:4, 1:4])
   mpg cyl disp  hp
1 21.0   6  160 110
2 21.0   6  160 110
3 22.8   4  108  93
4 21.4   6  258 110
```

#### 4. `base::rbind` cannot cope with missing columns

Just for completeness, since Abhilash Kandwal already said so in their answer.

#### 5. `base::rbind` handles named arguments differently

While `base::rbind` prepends argument names to rownames, `dplyr::bind_rows` has the option to add a dedicated ID column:

```
rbind(hi = mtcars[1:2, 1:4], bye = mtcars[3:4, 1:4])
                    mpg cyl disp  hp
hi.Mazda RX4       21.0   6  160 110
hi.Mazda RX4 Wag   21.0   6  160 110
bye.Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93
bye.Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110

dplyr::bind_rows(hi = mtcars[1:2, 1:4], bye = mtcars[3:4, 1:4], .id = "my_id")
  my_id  mpg cyl disp  hp
1    hi 21.0   6  160 110
2    hi 21.0   6  160 110
3   bye 22.8   4  108  93
4   bye 21.4   6  258 110
```

#### 6. `base::rbind` makes vector arguments into rows (and recycles them)

In contrast, `dplyr::bind_rows` adds columns (and therefore requires the elements of x to be named):

```
rbind(mtcars[1:2, 1:4], x = 1:2))
              mpg cyl disp  hp
Mazda RX4      21   6  160 110
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110
x               1   2    1   2

dplyr::bind_rows(mtcars[1:2, 1:4], x = c(a = 1, b = 2))
  mpg cyl disp  hp  a  b
1  21   6  160 110 NA NA
2  21   6  160 110 NA NA
3  NA  NA   NA  NA  1  2
```

#### 7. `base::rbind` is slower and requires more RAM

To bind a hundred medium-sized data frames (1k rows), `base::rbind` requires fifty times more RAM and is more than 15 times slower:

```
dfs = rep(list(df_1), 100)
bench::mark(
  "base::rbind" = do.call(rbind, dfs),
  "dplyr::bind_rows" = dplyr::bind_rows(dfs)
)[, 1:5]

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 base::rbind       47.23ms  48.05ms      20.0  104.48MB
2 dplyr::bind_rows   3.69ms   3.75ms     261.     2.39MB
```

Since I needed to bind lots of small data frames, here is a benchmark for that too. Both speed but especially RAM difference is quite striking:

```
dfs = rep(list(df_1[1:2, ]), 10^4)
bench::mark(
  "base::rbind" = do.call(rbind, dfs),
  "dplyr::bind_rows" = dplyr::bind_rows(dfs)
)[, 1:5]

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc
  <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>
1 base::rbind         1.65s    1.65s     0.605    1.56GB
2 dplyr::bind_rows  19.31ms  20.21ms    43.7    566.69KB
```

Finally, `help("rbind")` and `help("bind_rows")` are interesting to read, too.

Comment: I'd suggest adding that `bind_rows()` can combine data frames which contain same column names but in different order . For example `bind_rows()` can merge and append DF1: [`Column1`,`Column2`, `Column3`] and DF2: [`Column3`,`Column1`, `Column2`], while `rbind()` would require to resort them to have the same column sequence

Comment: Wait, that's not right. You can totally do e.g. `rbind(mtcars[, 1:3], mtcars[, 3:1])` and it works just fine, despite the fact the columns come in different order.