# How can you merge data frames one below the other instead of next to each other (left-right)?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two data sets as CSV files with identical columns.
I want to merge them so that they are listed one below the other.

I tried this code but this only puts them together left to right:

```
merge(1, 2, by="Col A")
```

I am looking to list them one above the other in the merged data set, not next to each other.

[image]

Comment: Just use `rbind`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bind_rows()` from dplyr. For a discussion why `bind_rows` can sometimes be preferrable over `rbind()` see [the discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42887217/8107362)

```
one <- mtcars[1:4, ]
two <- mtcars[11:14, ]

# You can supply data frames as arguments:
bind_rows(one, two)
```

Comment: please mark an answer as accepted if you pleased with it so the community knows the problem is solved