# Combining data sets vertically

Tags: r

Suppose I have three datasets

```
DF1=
Traj X Y
1   4 5
1   7 8
2   5 6
```

```
DF2=

Traj X Y
1   5 2
1   6 4
2   8 7
```

```
DF3=

Traj X Y
1   8 5
1   1 9
2   3 7
```

How can I combine them into one dataset like below:

```
DF1=

Traj X Y
1   4 5
1   7 8
2   5 6
1   5 2
1   6 4
2   8 7
1   8 5
1   1 9
2   3 7
```

I have many similar data that have similar elements and it would be easier to just combine them, unfortunately I don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, `rbind(DF1, DF2, DF3` (`rbind` stands for "row bind", i.e. "put rows together"). In tidyverse, `dplyr::bind_rows(DF1, DF2, DF3)` is slightly fancier.

If you already have a list of your data frames,

```
DFlist <- list(DF1, DF2, DF3)
do.call(DFlist, rbind)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do this

```
rbind(df1, df2, df3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to place it in a `list` and use `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
mget(ls(pattern = '^DF\\d+$')) %>%
       bind_rows
```

Answer (score 2):

This works also:

```
bind_rows(DF1, DF2, DF3)
```

Comment: how does this add to/differ from previously posted answers by me and @akrun?

Comment: See here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887217/difference-between-rbind-and-bind-rows-in-r>. At the time of my post I did not recognize the `bind_rows` from akrun. But anyway you can simply use `bind_rows` without `mget` .

Comment: My answer already refers to `bind_rows()` (in the second sentence), although it is not *quite* as explicitly stated as your answer. (I just edited my answer to make the implicit "`bind_rows` is called in the same way as `rbind`" more explicit ...)

Comment: Yes you are right Ben. But it was not a bad intention. I just read over the part with `bind_rows` in your post. Sorry for that. I have voted up your answer at the time I posted mine.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not downvoting your answer, just hesitating to upvote it.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Will take more care in future!