# What type of joining should I use

Tags: r, merge, bind

I have two databases with different numbers of columns. All columns of the second database are included in the second database. The patients in the two databases are also different. I need to merge the two databases. The function merge (or `_join` of `dplyr`) will not work in principle since I have to overlay the databases. The binding (`rowbind`) should not also works cause I have different columns. What is the simple way to do it?

```
mydata<-data.frame(
  ID=c(1,1,1,2,2),B=rep("b",5),C=rep("c",5),D=rep("d",5)
)

mydata2<-data.frame(ID=c(3,4),B=c("b2","b2"),C=c("c2","c2"))
```

The expected dataset is this below:

```
  ID  B  C    D
1  1  b  c    d
2  1  b  c    d
3  1  b  c    d
4  2  b  c    d
5  2  b  c    d
6  3 b2 c2 <NA>
7  4 b2 c2 <NA>
```

Comment: I guess you need `library(dplyr); bind_rows(mydata, mydata2)`

Comment: It is Ok, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mere `merge` should suffice

```
merge( mydata, mydata2, all=T )
  ID  B  C    D
1  1  b  c    d
2  1  b  c    d
3  1  b  c    d
4  2  b  c    d
5  2  b  c    d
6  3 b2 c2 <NA>
7  4 b2 c2 <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dplyr::full_join(mydata,mydata2)
```

seems to work .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind_rows()` to combine two data frames having different number of columns. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887217/difference-between-rbind-and-bind-rows-in-r)

```
library(dplyr) 

bind_rows(mydata, mydata2)
```